# No ext-locale package available in ExtJS 7.3

Tags: extjs, extjs7

For some weird reason, I'm getting this error:

> Cannot satisfy requirements for "ext-locale"! [ERR]    The following
> versions cannot be satisfied: [ERR]       App: ext-locale (No
> matches!) [ERR] Cannot resolve package requirements

Per official instructions, I added the requires to app.json

```
"classic": {
        "requires": [
            "ext-locale"
        ]
    },
```

I'm using the universal template:

```
"template": "universalclassicmodern"
```

I looked at `@sencha/ext-classic/`
but I can't see a locale directory there.

Do I have to manually install the package via npm?

Comment: Have you added the '"locale": "es",' to app.json?

Comment: Yes, it's there. What else do I have to do? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution:

If you install ExtJS via npm, like:

```
ext-gen app -a -t universalclassicmodern -n myApp
```

You'll need to install localization packages separately with:

```
npm i @sencha/ext-classic-locale
npm i @sencha/ext-modern-locale
```

And in app.json, you only need these settings regarding localization:

```
"locale": "es", // <-- Your locale here
    "requires": [      
        "ext-locale"
    ],...
```

Seems that you don't need to specify the locale for each build/tookit.

This guide should be updated and explain it:
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.4.0/guides/core_concepts/localization.html

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems these packages don't exist for 7.0.0-CE.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the **Classic** or **Modern** template:
Try to change the code like this.
Open app.json file, in global requires.

```
"requires": [
        "font-awesome",
        "locale"
    ],
"locale":"zh_CN",  //!!!Your localization parameters
```

Configure specific build options

```
"production": {
        "requires": [
            "locale"
        ],
        "locale":"zh_CN", //!!!Your localization parameters
        ...
},
"testing": {
    "requires": [
        "locale"
    ],
    "locale":"zh_CN",  //!!!Your localization parameters
    ...
},
"development": {
    "requires": [
        "locale"
    ],
    "locale":"zh_CN",  //!!!Your localization parameters
    ...
},
```

---

If you use the  **universal** template,Try to change the code like this.Open app.json file, in global requires.

```
"requires": [
        "font-awesome",
        "locale"
    ],
"locale": "zh_CN",  //!!!Your localization parameters
```

Then according to the official documentation, add "ext-locale" to the "requires" under the Classic and Modern nodes

```
"classic": {
     "requires": [
        "ext-locale"
     ],
     "locale": "zh_CN",  //!!!Your localization parameters
     .....
},
"modern": {
     "requires": [
         "ext-locale"
      ],
      "locale": "zh_CN",  //!!!Your localization parameters
      ...
}
```

Comment: I followed your exact instructions. Still no luck:
[INF] Processing Build Descriptor : desktop (development environment)
[ERR] Cannot satisfy requirements for "ext-locale"!
[ERR]    The following versions cannot be satisfied:
[ERR]       App: ext-locale (No matches!)
[ERR] Cannot resolve package requirements

Here's the entire file:
https://pastebin.com/X7b5RNbj

Comment: Did you try `locale` instead of `ext-locale` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried using "locale" inside classic->requires but it throws this error:
```[INF] Processing Build Descriptor : desktop (development environment)

[ERR] null```

Comment: I've revised my answer. I found it through my own tests these days

Comment: @Dinkheller seems that the problem happens only one you install ExtJS via NPM:
```ext-gen app -a -t universalclassicmodern -n myApp```
When you start project from the official .zip, it works, because it comes with classic/locale data. The NPM installation doesn't seem to bring the locales. Try it out.